# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.<init>(Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/BaseConstructor;)V

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am getting this error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.<init>(Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/BaseConstructor;)V` while trying to run some SeLion Test cases. These test cases are for a node js component. If I look at the dependency tree I am able to see this `org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23`. Also in the maven dependencies when i open the Yaml class, I can see that there is a constructor which takes a BaseConstructor. Please help me figure this out.

Comment: Can you add some snippets of the code you are using?

Comment: I think it has to do something with the java version. My intellij uses a different version of java from my eclipse and when I run it from intellij it works but on eclipse it does not work.

Comment: Did you find the solution to it?

Comment: Sort of... Just using a different version of java for this.